# Upgraded to 12.04 and now wont stay connected to secure network

Tags: 11.10, wireless, 12.04, upgrade

I upgraded today from 11.10, and now I cannot stay connected to my secure network for more than 10 or 15 seconds. I keep getting asked to put in my Network key.  I can however wireless tether connect through my droid with out a network key, and stay connected for as long as I want.

I've been poking around and have not been able to get this fixed on my own. I threw some codes in my terminal and came back with this.

```
*-network               
   description: Wireless interface
   product: BCM4321 802.11a/b/g/n
   vendor: Broadcom Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:0c:00.0
   logical name: eth1
   version: 03
   serial: 00:1f:e1:88:99:c4
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=5.100.82.38 ip=192.168.5.100 latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
   resources: irq:17 memory:f9ffc000-f9ffffff memory:f8000000-f80fffff
*-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: BCM4401-B0 100Base-TX
   vendor: Broadcom Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
   logical name: eth0
   version: 02
   serial: 00:21:70:6d:3f:21
   size: 10Mbit/s
   capacity: 100Mbit/s
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list ethernet physical mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=b44 driverversion=2.0 duplex=half latency=64 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Mbit/s
   resources: irq:17 memory:f9bfe000-f9bfffff
xbostonirishx@linux-box-1720:~$
```

Now none of this means anything to me. I don't know if this is pertaining to my verizon card, that's embeded in my laptop, or my wireless card....

Comment: What is your "secure network"?  SSH, VPN, IPsec, or simply WPA2/PSK (WiFi) ?

Answer (score 0):

I think selecting the checkbox "Available to all users" fixed this for me... it was either that or taking out the word "Auto" in the Connection name... either way, I was getting the exact same thing until I did that.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was going in to the network settings, editing the connection, and typing the network key in there.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem while updating from 11.10 to 12.04. 
(no need to use terminal on this one)
I fixed this problem by doing this:

1) click on the dash home button

2) now search for *network connection*, click on it.

3) a window will pop-up with 5 different tabs, click on the one that says *wireless*

4) now highlight your wireless connection and click on the button that says *edit*

5) another window will pop-up with 4 different tabs, click on the one that says *security*

6) right next to *key* type your password

7) **very important** click on **save**

this should have fixed this tedious problem